# Probability - Pack of Cards (Changed Random Variable)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, card-games

I just had a tricky question about calculation of expectation of a variable.
So, we have a pack of $52$ cards and $X_1\cdots X_{50}$ are outcomes of first $50$ draws.
Each $X$ can take values from $1-52$
If we have a variable $A = X_1- 2X_2 + 3X_3$, how do we calculate expectation of $X$?
I tried thinking hard but the fact that $A$ is combination of $3$ variables, each having $52$ outcomes and me not have learned expression of one random variable in terms of others is making the job really difficult.

So, how do we solve this kind of a question?

Comment: I assume the cards are just numbered 1 to 52 and drawn without replacement?

Comment: Actually they're drawn with replacement. Forgot to mention

Answer (score 2):

The expected value of all the $X_i$ is $\frac{53}2$ since all of $1,\dots,52$ are equally likely to be drawn, so that of $X_1-2X_2+3X_3$ equals that of $X_1-2X_1+3X_1$, i.e. the answer is $2X_1=53$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! Since we're taking with replacement independent random variables, would the general expectation expression be like: E(Xi) = 1/52.1 + 1/52 . 2 + ...1/52 .52?

Comment: . represents multiplication. So, 1/52.1 is read as 1/52 multiplied by 1 and so on

Comment: @Charles Y E S.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Expectation for a sum of independant variables is the sum of expectations of each variable.

Comment: @Lourrran: The linearity of expectation isn't restricted to independent variables.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, but that has nothing to do with independence; that's just the definition of the expectation of a random variable.